# Is there a way to place particles as a background but don't have to disable interactivity?

Tags: javascript, html, css

I have a canvas particles and want to put that in to a background with interactivity, no change.
Is there any way to do that?
Html:

```
<html>
    <head>
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="css.css">
    </head>
    <body>
        <div id="particle-canvas"></div>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="particle.min.js"></script>
        <script type="text/javascript">
            var particleCanvas = new ParticleNetwork(canvasDiv, options);
        </script>
    </body>
</html>
```

CSS:

```
body {
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  overflow: hidden;
}
#particle-canvas {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
}
```

JS:

```
var options = {
    particleColor: '#fff',
    background: '#1a252f',
    interactive: true,
    speed: 'fast',
    density: 'medium'
};
var particleCanvas = new ParticleNetwork(document.getElementById('particle-canvas'), options);
```

Comment: Particles allow interactivity by *default*. Nothing in your code is preventing interaction.

Comment: What on earth is a "particle"? (I know you're referring to `particle.min.js`, but the rest of us don't!). We aren't here to help with libraries we know nothing about. Where did you get it from? Have you read their docs? Or read their source?

Comment: @ObsidianAge yeah I now but is there.. how to put that as a background so we can WRITE heading/description also WITH interactivity, don't have to disable it

Comment: Could you put up a working snippet into your answer. The snippet system allows you to add external libraries. Also please could you describe what interactivity you want - it's not usual to interact with something called a background, so do you want to interact with stuff that's on top of the background. And what options are you setting to particle? And is it particles js you are using?